# Samsung Galaxy S3 not showing in select device list mono for android visual studio 2012

Tags: android, visual-studio, mono, galaxy, samsung-mobile

I am having an issue deploying my mono for android app on the Samsung Galaxy S3 through Visual Studio 2012.  The select device list does not show the Samsung Galaxy S3 device even though it is plugged into PC through USB and recognised as a GT-I9300 in my PC device list.  I have installed the Samsung’s Kies application and updated the phones firmware but with no luck. Previously I had been deploying my app to the Samsung Galaxy ACE plus with no issue.

Do I have to enable some settings on the phone to make this work? Does the Mono SDK for Visual Studio recognise this particular device?  Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 6):

Try going to Settings > Developer, and check the USB Debugging box (and stay-awake box for good measure).

Short of that, see here:

[Can't debug app on device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17450918/cant-debug-app-on-device)

Hope that helps.

Comment: If you can't see the Developer option under Settings, go to "About Device" and click "Build Number" 5 times. I thought this was a joke but it's what turns on Developer mode so you can see Settings>Developer (at least this was the fix on my Samsung Tablet).

Answer (score 1):

Have you installed the USB drivers for the device? See [this link](http://developer.android.com/tools/extras/oem-usb.html) for more information.

Comment: Yes installed USB drivers and latest firmware.  I have fixed the issue,  You need to enable USB debugging under the settings -> developer options of the phone

Comment: Direct link to the USB driver:
http://www.samsung.com/us/support/owners/product/SCH-I535RWBVZW