# Can't debug app on device

Tags: android, ddms, samsung-mobile

All of my devices work just fine.  This particular device, which is a Samsung, does not.

When I plug the phone in, the phone shows up in the DDMS device's list.  However, none of the apps/processes show up.  This is the only device this happens for.

Yes, USB debugging is enabled.

Yes, debuggable is set to true in the manifest.

Like I said, every other device works fine.  I can plug another device in 2 seconds later and it works great.

The device is running Android 4.0.4.

Any ideas?

Comment: is a custom rom on Samsung, with some custom setting, which doesn't allow debug? or some custom settings related to Kies? Did you try enable/disable debug and restart device, unplug / plug usb cable, restart PC?

Comment: It's a friend's phone.  He's not technical.  He's done nothing fancy to it.  I've tried all of your suggestions other than restarting my computer (OS X).

Comment: when you have an "unknown error occurred" must try that too :)  Not sure why, but sometimes needed to restart my mac mini, the softwares aren't perfect and just hang on, even if written by Apple or Google. I am developing Android from mac mini (OS X). Try delete the old build ( manage apps, remove) No other ideas.

Comment: I've updated the SDK and now it works.  Apparently, if there have been multiple updates to the SDK, you have to close, relaunch, and update for every time the SDK has been updated.  Brainless.

Comment: yeah, Android SDK must me always the latest...

Answer (score 3):

I had same issue, everything was according to what is necessary to run on my device. If you are developing on windows 7, run eclipse as administrator.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem - Samsung S3 kept opening the app, wait on black screen, and crash.

I solved it by moving all the 'drawable-large-hdpi' images into 'drawable-xxhdpi'.

Turns out  the S3 was pulling in these higher res images, and so ran out of memory, which quit the app.

Answer (score 1):

I'm on Android 4.4.4, but just ran into a similar issue. I have a Moto X 2nd gen and a Nexus 7 and neither would allow me to debug, even though USB Debugging was enabled on the devices and the applicable USB drivers were installed. When plugging in either device, the device would give me a message saying "USB debugging connected", but the computer didn't recognize the device (as a media device or otherwise).

The fix was to (on android 4.4.4) go into Settings -> Storage -> menu button (dots in top right) -> USB computer connection -> turn on Media device (MTP).

I had turned this setting off thinking "I'm not using this as a media device, I just want to debug apps on it"... but apparently the setting is required for debugging to work. I didn't see this in the documentation or in any other posts, so I thought I'd share. Hopefully this saves someone else from wasting time on this.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know if my writing will give u the answer.

Yesterday i bought China phone, and this is my first Android phone after using Nokia Windows Phone since 2009. Im too lazy to check the model, but it stated MTxxxx somethings, and i do root, but the problem occurs with "USB Debug" things. So for last 23 hours, i do study about this. It help me nothing, till i try to root it with two software; Kingo and Iroot in the same time. And now im rooting my device while writing here... on Kingo, it stated 35% and iroot just booting and rooting, yet it not done.

Minute 3

My phone is restart. and Kingo now 43% while Iroot stated that i fail to root my android and keep asking to "retry" but i just ignore it. Keep going with Kingo now....

Minute 5

Kingo keep reciting the root at 45% now. Too slow. And now it restarting my android phone. Now it 49%.

Minute 7

Kingo now rooting at 59%. I hope this will keep going while im eating KFC and typing, in the same time i wanna play CS 1.6... damn. Faster faster! 60% and restarting. 3 times already since then. After restart it was 64%.

Minute 9

Restart at 70% rooting.

Minute 11

Restart with 71% rooting. Too slow... im typing faster than android' rooting....cool.

Minute 12

Restart with 72% rooting. I think it would restart with every gain of percentage? Which means 100 - 72 = 28 times to restart? I check the battery, while it cable-ing so it charging. Phew....

Minute 13

Restart with 74% rooting. Maybe this is the hard part of rooting i guess. Seem like Eminem's dilemma before join hiphop industry. And now restart again with 75% rooting... meh!

Minute 15

77% rooting and restarting.... and 78%, restart again.

Minute 17

79% rooting and restart. I kept waiting and writing... andd 80% rooting is restarting.

... AND IT DONE!

Answer (score -4):

It's a long time ago for me but I can remeber that I must enable debugging on the device. Something like: "Go to the menu and press some button 10 times". See the developersite form google. There was the manual.

Comment: **"USB debugging is enabled."**, so useless answer.